# How to make RSU as mobile node (car)?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm currently using veins to connect my sumo traffic network with omnet++
In my sumo network, I use 2 types of vehicle, bus and car

My questions,

- Does omnet++ support **RSU as mobile** nodes?
  what I mean is RSU is not placed in a fix place but can be mobile as a node (car), based on the type car from sumo network.
  for example, vehicle type bus as RSU and vehicle type car as mobile node.
  So that all of vehicle-type-bus from sumo can be RSU-as-mobile-node
  If it is supported, how it works?

Thank you!

Comment: For your second question, why not use a car itself? Just put the application you use in the RSU inside the car (?)
Or are there any further constraints?

Comment: StackOverflow is all about collecting good answers to good questions. For this to work it's best not to mix multiple questions into one. If you don't mind, could you please move your second bullet point to a new question?

Comment: I describe in more detail on the new edited question. So I need to get the type of vehicle from sumo first and use only type bus act as RSU. 
so can I just add the module for RSU to the car? @floxyz

Comment: Sorry for not meeting the rule, since I'm newbie in stack overflow. I already edit my question, and I remove the first question since it similar with my question in another post. Hope it can provide clear explanation @ChristophSommer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veins 4a2 and earlier do not support this functionality. The next version will support it.

Comment: Is there any way to use RSU module applications in the mobile nodes (car) or on certain type of vehicle, so that it can works like RSU?  
Thank you for the explanation sir.